# A text search option is not installed or not properly configured.. SQLCODE=-21000, SQLSTATE=42724

Tags: database, db2, db2-luw

I getting the following error when using "contains" function.

A text search option is not installed or not properly configured.. SQLCODE=-21000, SQLSTATE=42724

DB2 is 10.5 on Linux.

How I can enable text search on existing db?

As db2ts command is not found we I try to unable

db2ts "ENABLE DATABASE FOR TEXT"

I have created a new db but still not found the db2ts exe.

Comment: The Text Search component must be selected during DB2 installation; it is not installed by default.

Comment: Is it possible to install "text search" component now on existing install db2, OR I have to install fresh installation?

Comment: How to install text_search component on existing installed db2 instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have installed TEXT_SEARCH component  on existing db2 instance.

1. db2stop
2. db2iupdt -j "TEXT_SEARCH,TEXT_SEARCH_Port" DB_Instance_Name
3. then start the instance (db2start)